# Liblinear usage format

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, syntax, liblinear

I am using .NET implementation of liblinear in my C# code by the following nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Liblinear/

But in the readme file of liblinear, the format for x is:

`struct problem` describes the problem:

```
    struct problem
    {
        int l, n;
        int *y;
        struct feature_node **x;
        double bias;
    };

where `l` is the number of training data. If bias >= 0, we assume
that one additional feature is added to the end of each data
instance. `n` is the number of feature (including the bias feature
if bias >= 0). `y` is an array containing the target values. (integers
in classification, real numbers in regression) And `x` is an array
of pointers, each of which points to a sparse representation (array
of feature_node) of one training vector.

For example, if we have the following training data:

    LABEL       ATTR1   ATTR2   ATTR3   ATTR4   ATTR5
    -----       -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
    1           0       0.1     0.2     0       0
    2           0       0.1     0.3    -1.2     0
    1           0.4     0       0       0       0
    2           0       0.1     0       1.4     0.5
    3          -0.1    -0.2     0.1     1.1     0.1

and bias = 1, then the components of problem are:

    l = 5
    n = 6

    y -> 1 2 1 2 3

    x -> [ ] -> (2,0.1) (3,0.2) (6,1) (-1,?)
         [ ] -> (2,0.1) (3,0.3) (4,-1.2) (6,1) (-1,?)
         [ ] -> (1,0.4) (6,1) (-1,?)
         [ ] -> (2,0.1) (4,1.4) (5,0.5) (6,1) (-1,?)
         [ ] -> (1,-0.1) (2,-0.2) (3,0.1) (4,1.1) (5,0.1) (6,1) (-1,?)
```

But, in the example showing java implementation:
https://gist.github.com/hodzanassredin/6682771

```
problem.x <- [|
                        [|new FeatureNode(1,0.); new FeatureNode(2,1.)|]
                        [|new FeatureNode(1,2.); new FeatureNode(2,0.)|]
                    |]// feature nodes
problem.y <- [|1.;2.|] // target values
```

which means his data set is:

```
1 0 1
2 2 0
```

So, he is not storing the nodes as per sparse format of liblinear. Does, anyone know of correct format for x for liblinear implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't address exactly the library you mentioned, I can offer you an alternative. The
Accord.NET Framework has recently incorporated all of LIBLINEAR's algorithms in its machine learning 
namespaces. It is also [available through NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.MachineLearning/).

In this library, the direct syntax to create a linear support vector machine from in-memory data is

```
// Create a simple binary AND
// classification problem:

double[][] problem =
{
    //             a    b    a + b
    new double[] { 0,   0,     0    },
    new double[] { 0,   1,     0    },
    new double[] { 1,   0,     0    },
    new double[] { 1,   1,     1    },
};

// Get the two first columns as the problem
// inputs and the last column as the output

// input columns
double[][] inputs = problem.GetColumns(0, 1);

// output column
int[] outputs = problem.GetColumn(2).ToInt32();

// However, SVMs expect the output value to be
// either -1 or +1. As such, we have to convert
// it so the vector contains { -1, -1, -1, +1 }:
//
outputs = outputs.Apply(x => x == 0 ? -1 : 1);
```

After the problem is created, one can learn a linear SVM using

```
// Create a new linear-SVM for two inputs (a and b)
SupportVectorMachine svm = new SupportVectorMachine(inputs: 2);

// Create a L2-regularized L2-loss support vector classification
var teacher = new LinearDualCoordinateDescent(svm, inputs, outputs)
{
    Loss = Loss.L2,
    Complexity = 1000,
    Tolerance = 1e-5
};

// Learn the machine
double error = teacher.Run(computeError: true);

// Compute the machine's answers for the learned inputs
int[] answers = inputs.Apply(x => Math.Sign(svm.Compute(x)));
```

This assumes, however, that your data is already in-memory. If you wish to load your data from the 
disk, **from a file in libsvm sparse format**, you can use the framework's [SparseReader class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_IO_SparseReader.htm). 
An example on how to use it can be found below:

```
// Suppose we are going to read a sparse sample file containing
//  samples which have an actual dimension of 4. Since the samples
//  are in a sparse format, each entry in the file will probably
//  have a much smaller number of elements.
// 
int sampleSize = 4;

// Create a new Sparse Sample Reader to read any given file,
//  passing the correct dense sample size in the constructor
// 
SparseReader reader = new SparseReader(file, Encoding.Default, sampleSize);

// Declare a vector to obtain the label
//  of each of the samples in the file
// 
int[] labels = null;

// Declare a vector to obtain the description (or comments)
//  about each of the samples in the file, if present.
// 
string[] descriptions = null;

// Read the sparse samples and store them in a dense vector array
double[][] samples = reader.ReadToEnd(out labels, out descriptions);
```

Afterwards, one can use the `samples` and `labels` vectors as the inputs and outputs of the problem, 
respectively.

I hope it helps.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of this library. I am answering this question in the sincere hope it 
can be useful for the OP, since not long ago I also faced the same problems. If a moderator thinks 
this looks like spam, feel free to delete. However, I am only posting this because I think it might 
help others. I even came across this question by mistake while searching for existing C# 
implementations of LIBSVM, not LIBLINEAR.